# R plot two series of means with 95% confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I am trying to plot the following data

```
factor <- as.factor(c(1,2,3))
V1_mean <- c(100,200,300)
V2_mean <- c(350,150,60)
V1_stderr <- c(5,9,3)
V2_stderr <- c(12,9,10)

plot <- data.frame(factor,V1_mean,V2_mean,V1_stderr,V2_stderr)
```

I want to create a plot with factor on the x-axis, value on the y-axis and seperate lines for V1 and V2 (hence the points are the values of V1_mean on one line and V2_mean on the other). I would also like to add error bars for these means based on V1_stderr and V2_stderr

Many thanks

Comment: @DavidArenburg I actually want 95% CIs so +/- 1.96 standard errors

Comment: what exactly is your problem? maybe this is helpful: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)

Comment: @beetroot my problem is getting the data into a form where I can use the method in that tutorial, seems I need a factor variable denoting whether the measurement is from V1 or V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure regarding your desired output, but here's a possible solution.

First of all, I wouldn't call your data `plot` as this is a stored function in R which is being commonly used

Second of all, when you want to plot two lines in `ggplot` you'll usually have to tide your data using functions such as `melt` (from `reshape2` package) or `gather` (from `tidyr` package).

Here's an a possible approach

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dat <- data.frame(factor, V1_mean, V2_mean, V1_stderr, V2_stderr)
mdat <- cbind(melt(dat[1:3], "factor"), melt(dat[c(1, 4:5)], "factor"))
names(mdat) <- make.names(names(mdat), unique = TRUE)

ggplot(mdat, aes(factor, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = variable)) + # You can also add `geom_point(aes(group = variable)) + ` if you want to see the actual points
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - value.1, ymax = value + value.1))
```

[image]